# ffmpeg find files PHP exec

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Having no success with ffmpeg.  How do i check if a file even exists?

I have the file

`$mp3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/youtube_channels/major.mp3";`

I've attempted to find the file with `exec()` but nothing is returned.  How do i solve?  I'm totally lost.

`var_dump(exec("/usr/include/ffmpeg -i $mp3"));`

All that is returned **string(0) ""**

when i check phpinfo ffmpeg is installed and when i type `exec("whereis ffmpeg")` what is returned is `/usr/include/ffmpeg`.

I've been stuck on this for 2 days, how do i solve this?

Comment: I would suggest you to use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of `exec()` because it offers you the best control over the call.

Comment: The variable `$mp3` should be put into [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) so it does not break when there are special characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `file_exists($full_path_to_file)`

See [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

In your case

```
if(file_exists($mp3)) {
    //exec....
}
```

EDIT as per comment below:

Try to output all the lines

```
$output = [];
exec("/usr/include/ffmpeg -i $mp3 2>&1", $output);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: I know the file exists but when i attempt to convert the file ffmpeg does nothing! How do i know ffmpeg knows the file exists?

Comment: Did you try running it through a terminal/command prompt to see if it works before using exec in php ? - > Also try to use the $output argument from exec. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by making sure that php can execute ffmpeg using `shell_exec`;

```
$out=shell_exec("/usr/include/ffmpeg 2>&1 1> /dev/null");
echo $out;
```

If you get a string like this

> ffmpeg version N-81373-gf84cff8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg
>   developers built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
>   20160609 configuration: --prefix=/home/ben/ffmpeg_build
>   --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/ben/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=- ... (etc)

then you're in business.  Next try to run it with your file:

```
$out=shell_exec("/usr/include/ffmpeg -i $mp3 2>&1 1> /dev/null");
echo $out;
```

and see if it's pulling info about your file:

> ...Duration: 00:00:06.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2317 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264...(etc)